# SQL - update to put values into numbered columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have a set of queries to update a table (`boxes`) with codes from another table (`cards`) according to their sequence number. Cards with a sequence number of 1 go in a column called `code_1` in the table `boxes`, and so on for a finite number of possible sequence numbers. Since it is finite, I can do something like:

```
update b
    set code_1 = c.codes
    from boxes as b inner join cards as c
        on b.service_id = c.service_id and c.sequence_number = 1;
update b
    set code_2 = c.codes
    from boxes as b inner join cards as c
        on b.service_id = c.service_id and c.sequence_number = 2;
update b
    set code_3 = c.codes
    from boxes as b inner join cards as c
        on b.service_id = c.service_id and c.sequence_number = 3;
...
update b
    set code_n = c.codes
    from boxes as b inner join cards as c
        on b.service_id = c.service_id and c.sequence_number = n;
```

but my question is: is there a way to write a single query that will update all of the columns appropriately based on the sequence number in the source?

Comment: Is `n` a known and fixed value, or can it vary?

Comment: @PhilipKelley `n` varies for a given `service_id` but does have a max value so I can hard code it if need be.

Comment: Also, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @PhilipKelley SSMS - I'll add that as a tag too thanks,

Comment: Best to tag it with the version of MS SQL Sever that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with below code

```
UPDATE b
    SET code_1 = CASE sequence_number
        WHEN 1 THEN 3
        WHEN 2 THEN 4
        WHEN 3 THEN 5
    END,
    code_2 = CASE sequence_number
        WHEN 1 THEN 'New Title 1'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'New Title 2'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'New Title 3'
    END
WHERE sequence_number IN (1,2)
```

As far as I know, you can achieve multiple updates with multiple from this. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
update b set code_1 = (select c.codes from cards as c on b.service_id = i.service_id and c.sequence_number = 1), 
code_2= (select c.codes from cards as c on b.service_id = i.service_id and c.sequence_number = 2),
code_3= (select c.codes from cards as c on b.service_id = i.service_id and c.sequence_number = 3),
. 
. 
. 
code_n= (select c.codes from cards as c on b.service_id = i.service_id and c.sequence_number = n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... If you dont want to hardcode it, maybe you can use a method with a loop instead. I am not super strong in sp's, but something like this:

```
DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = 1, @codeNumber int;

WHILE (SELECT boxID FROM boxes )< (select max(boxID) as boxIDMax from boxes )
BEGIN  
SET @codeNumber= <get_your_codeID_here_with_select_where_boxID=codeID>

update b
    set @codeNumber = c.codes
    from boxes as b inner join cards as c
        on b.service_id = i.service_id and c.sequence_number = boxID;

SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1;  

END
```

Comment: This will not work, as you cannot use variables (`@codeNumber`) to specify the column being updated. Use the loop to create and then execute a Dynamic SQL statement--but that would still be several queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it by using `PIVOT`

```
;WITH T AS (
select * from 
    (select * from cards ) src 
        pivot ( MAX(codes) for sequence_number IN ([1],[2],[3],...,[n])) pvt
)
update b 
SET 
    code_1 = T.[1],
    code_2 = T.[2],
    code_3 = T.[3],
    ....,
    code_n = T.[n]
from
    boxes b 
    inner join T ON  b.service_id = T.service_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the number of columns to be updated is not known at design time means that, strictly speaking, this cannot be done in a single query. You would need to build and then execute a Dynamic SQL query to do this.

@Troels answer is one way to approach this—loop over N, and for each iteration issue and update. This would be more convenient code than what you currently have and is probably what you really want, but is not a single query.

To make it a single query you’d have to:

- Dynamically build the query, with N “Items”
- Start by building a the join from Boxes into Cards
- Use this as the subquery within a pivot statement, generating a column for each Item (this is where dynamic SQL is mandatory)
- Make the pivot query the first part of a CTE
- Next, join boxes onto the CTE tableset, by service_id
- Make it an update statement, with N (dynamically generated) Items in the Set clause, with the value set to the appropriate column from the pivot set (and be sure to check for and handle NULLs properly)

This would be a pain to write and a minor headache to make changes to over time. Unless there’s a very strong reason (needs to be a single transaction?) I’d start with @Troels version and add in dynamic SQL.

And if course it has to be said that the best solution is to normalize table `boxes` so that it doesn’t contain an unknown number of rows—say, `Boxes` (primary key `box_id`) and BoxContents (primary key `box_id, sequence_number`)

...@sarslan's pivot answer came in while I was writing this, and is exactly what I'm talking about. It works if you know N, but has to be built and run ad hoc if you don't.